# Reading data from Serial port

Tags: java, serial-port

I have a requirement where i have to read data streams coming on serial port. I am using javax.comm API for same.

When I try to list ports, using below code I never get any port list.

```
portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
System.out.println("start: "+portList.hasMoreElements());
```

It returns false.

Can anyone help me if I am missing anything?

---

My PS2 port didn't came in list. Is there any other way to list PS2 port??

My full code is as below,

```
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
       portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
       System.out.println("portid: "+portId.getName());
    }
```

output

```
portid: COM1
portid: COM3
portid: LPT1
```

My actual requirement is to read data on USB port. I was facing issues using JUSB and it didn't work. So I decided to get serial to USb converter and read on serial port. But, there is no such convertable available in market.

Now, thinking of another work around I was able to get a PS2 to usb converter. It would be great if you could help me listing PS2 port using Java and read/write to it or suggest some API for same on windows platform.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: which javax.comm library you are using and what is your system? I am using rxtx and it works well.

Comment: I am also using rxtx and it worked for me too. The thing missing was configuration in eclipse related to .dll file as explained in link below,  http://www.intellog.com/blog/?p=255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see: 
http://www.intellog.com/blog/?p=255 and http://www.coderanch.com/t/535173/Streams/java/CommPortIdentifier-getPortIdentifiers-empty (the latter points to the first)

Oracle does not offer the binaries for windows (assuming that you're on windows): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

Comment: Thanks for useful link, it worked. I am able to list ports connected to my System.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).
Then you can use something like that:

```
 CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/tty1");
 CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open("owner-name", 2000);
 SerialPort serialport;
 if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
   serialPort = (SerialPort)commPort;
   serialPort.setSerialPortParams(rate, databits, stopbits, parity);
 }
 InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
 OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: Thanks Ortang. I am able to list my serial port now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu and my computer does not have any serial/pararel port but I need to develop on it.

You need to simulate this ports in this case.

My answer:

[serial port identification with java on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669379/serial-port-identification-with-java-on-ubuntu/21567949#21567949)