# serial port identification with java on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, serial-port

I'm trying to connect a serial application on ubuntu with Java
After searching and reading resources,I add comm.jar and RXTXcomm.jar in the library.
I use the following code to identify the comports. In my system there are three ports but it is showing false in `ports.hasMoreElements()` method.
Kindly look into the code and help me.

```
String wantedPortName = "/dev/ttya";
///dev/ttyS0 و /dev/ttyS1 نیز تست شد
Enumeration portIdentifiers = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
CommPortIdentifier portId = null;  // will be set if port found
while (portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements())
{
    CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers.nextElement();
    if(pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL &&
      pid.getName().equals(wantedPortName)) 
  {
    portId = pid;
    break;
  }
}
if(portId == null)
{
     System.err.println("Could not find serial port " + wantedPortName);
     System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using Ubuntu, and my notebook does not have any serial or paralel ports.

So, you have to simulate this kind of port:

```
apt-get install socat
```

Run it:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0, pty,raw,echo=0
```

According to output, pay attention to "devices" created:

```
2014/02/05 01:04:32 socat[7411] N PTY is /dev/pts/2
2014/02/05 01:04:32 socat[7411] N PTY is /dev/pts/3
2014/02/05 01:04:32 socat[7411] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

Stop socat [CTRL]+[C] and symlink it to a location that RXTX will recognise as a device, due to "tty" prefix:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/pts/2 /dev/ttyUSB02
sudo ln -s /dev/pts/3 /dev/ttyUSB03
```

Now, run socat again

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

Now, using following code, you will see 2 virtual ports:

```
        Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();//this line was false
        System.out.println(portList.hasMoreElements());

        while(portList.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println("Has more elements");
             CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
               if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                    System.out.println(portId.getName());
               }
               else{
                     System.out.println(portId.getName());
               }
        }
```

system.out:

```
true
Has more elements
/dev/ttyUSB03
Has more elements
/dev/ttyUSB02
```

Comment: I followed your instruction but still get `false` at starting line. not able to entering Has more elements constraint.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu? It's a Virtual Machine?

Comment: yes ubuntu.. yeah i know above commands i fired from terminal but when i used your following code.. it returns `false`.

Comment: I think it might be about RxTx versions because they changed how they look for serial ports. http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Trouble_shooting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are filtering out the port you want. A /dev/tty is a special character device... not a serial port so

```
if(pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL &&
  pid.getName().equals(wantedPortName))
```

should **never** match your string.

To prove this, try iterating over your available ports. I don't know if a tty can can be detected by RXTX but play with it and let us know.

Ref: 
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Discovering_available_comm_ports

EDIT:
So you don't have any serial devices to test with? All I sat is make sure you have everything installed properly, including the properties file as described in this file.

http://rxtx.qbang.org/pub/rxtx/rxtx-2.0-7pre2/INSTALL

Once done, install a null modem emulator or find a serial device to test with.

Comment: this if statment is on the while statment and while statment return false .
So the program does not execute this if!!!

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't like tty! Do you have an RS-232 device or similar to test if rxtx sees it? RXTX can be picky setup and config.

Comment: Unfortunately do not have RS-232 device or similar to test rxtx
please help me!